# Connecting ASP.NET MVC webApp and window mobile/windows phone7 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-phone-7, windows-mobile

last year I made really simple blog system. it allows user to authorize, posting, commenting. Now I want to create windows mobile/wp7 application that can adding new posts to my blog. But I have no idea how should it work. Should my web app share some api for this or my phone app should just sending specified request to server? I'm interessting how do facebook phone apps work? How they pass data to fb etc.

It would be great if anyone knows book, tutorial or something about connecting web app and phone app. I rather need app architecture tutorials than codes.

PS I know I can just open phone browser and login on website but I want to do it for fun :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of approaching this is create a few actions in your controllers to return data in a format that is friendly to a WP7 app, for example, return JSON rather than HTML.

In your WP7 app you will make HTTP requests to these actions and receive the data in JSON format. From there it's up to you to handle that information on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

What is the back-end of the blog system? Almost any DB data can now be exposed out as an OData Service that can be consumed on a Windows Phone app & also provide CRUD operations. Is OData a possibility?

Check out these two posts for details:

1. http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Producing-and-Consuming-OData-in-a-Silverlight-and-Windows-Phone-7-application.aspx
2. http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Connecting-Azure-Windows-Phone-through-OData.aspx

The second one does talk about how a central data store can be shared between web & mobile apps.

Hope this helps!